# How to get access to a variable that is in filter from a directive?

Tags: angularjs

So I have this directive:

```
.directive('iwSubmit', function () {
    return function (scope, element) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if(event.which === 13) {
                scope.$apply(function (){
                    scope.addField();
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});
```

And in this variable I make this call: `scope.addField()` and there I need to pass an ellement from an array, that currently is in my custom filter(`resultsArr`) to be exact.

```
.filter('iwSearch', function() {
        return function(items, term) {
            if (term !== undefined) {
                var newTerm = term.split(' ');
                var resultsArr = items.filter(function(item) {
                    // Check against new term whether it's a match.
                    var matches = 0;
                    var newItem = item.split(' ');
                    for (var i = 0; i < newItem.length; i++) {
                        //iterate over search term and check that all matches
                        if (newItem[i].indexOf(newTerm[i]) !== -1) matches++
                    }
                    return (matches >= newTerm.length);
                });
                return resultsArr;
            } else {
                return items;
            }
        }
    })
```

So how can I get access to this `resultsArr` from `iwSubmit` directive?

```
<div class="btn-group btn-xs" dropdown keyboard-nav is-open="status.isopenFields">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="simple-btn-keyboard-nav">
    <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="item in availableFields | iwSearch: available_fields_query">
      <a href="#" ng-click="addField(item)">{{item | toUserListHeader}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <input iw-submit="addFirst()" iw-click dropdown-toggle ng-model="available_fields_query" ng-disabled="disabled" placeholder="Add New Field" id="test">
</div>
```

Maybe I can use $rootScope?

Comment: So, you want to call that filter from the directive, right? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter

Comment: @JBNizet not exactly, I just want to get access to a variable from a filter. To make it global in a sense.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The resultsArr variable value is computed from the arguments passed to the filter function. So, let's say this filter is used 10 times, with 10 different arguments, in the application. What should the directive do? You should explain what this filter is for, what this directive is for, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @JBNizet as you can see, I have a dropdown list that is being populated, and each entry triggers a function on click, to which I pass ```item``` variable. But I want to make it so, if you just press Enter, it automatically calls ```addField()``` on the first result from the filter, which is ```resultsArr[0]```